# How to join JsonResult and return a single result - C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to join multiple JsonResults into a single named list to get it in angularJS. 
This is my function :-

```
List<AdminBundle> abundleList = new List<AdminBundle>();

aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.Board;
Func<JsonResult> functionBoard = new Func<JsonResult>(() => FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
JsonResult resBoard = await Task.Factory.StartNew<JsonResult>(functionBoard);

aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.Class;
Func<JsonResult> functionClass = new Func<JsonResult>(() => FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
JsonResult resClass = await Task.Factory.StartNew<JsonResult>(functionClass);

aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.ClassSubject;
Func<JsonResult> functionClassSubject = new Func<JsonResult>(() => FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
JsonResult resClassSubject = await Task.Factory.StartNew<JsonResult>(functionClassSubject);

aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.ClassMaterial;
Func<JsonResult> functionClassMaterial = new Func<JsonResult>(() => FetchTblData(aBundleFetch));
JsonResult resClassMaterial = await Task.Factory.StartNew<JsonResult>(functionClassMaterial);
```

I tried this:-

```
var result = new { resBoard.Data + resClass.Data + resClassSubject.Data + resClassMaterial.Data };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And this:-

```
JsonResult resultFinal = resBoard.Data  + resClass.Data + resClassSubject.Data + resClassMaterial.Data;
```

But they are not working. Also I want to fetch different lists via their names in my AngularJS:-

```
$scope.ClearAndGetTblData = function (TblName) {
        $scope.TblData = [{ ListType: "Board" }];
        FetchListFactory.TblDataList($scope.TblData).then(function (d) {

            //This is where I want to fetch the returned result
            $scope.BoardList = d.data.BoardList;
            $scope.ClassList = d.data.ClassList;
            $scope.ClassSubjectList = d.data.ClassSubjectList;
            $scope.MaterialList = d.data.MaterialList;

            $scope.ShowTableWithName(TblName);
            if ($scope.BoardList != null && $scope.BoardList.length != 0) {
                $scope.AvailableListTextToShow = "";
            }
            else {
                $scope.AvailableListTextToShow = "No Data Available";
            }
            $scope.BoardTextToShow = "Select Board";
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Cannot Load Class Data');
        })
    }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of errors in your code:

1. There is no good reason for you to be using `Task.Factory.StartNew`
2. You cannot combine `JsonResult` like that
3. Even if you could, `{ ... } + { ... }` wouldn't yield a valid JSON

So, taking all of this into account:

1. Make `FetchTblData` return a `IEnumerable<T>` - noone outside `Controller`s should use ASP.NET MVC-specific classes
2. Concatenate the results using `IEnumerable<T>.AddRange`
3. Given the name `FetchTblData` seems to imply a database connection, make it an `async Task<IEnumerable<T>>`.

With all of these changes, you should end up with something similar to this (notice that I standarised the names of your variables and methods):

```
bundleFetch.ListType = Constants.Board;
var boardData = await FetchTableDataAsync(bundleFetch);

bundleFetch.ListType = Constants.Class;
var classData = await FetchTableDataAsync(bundleFetch);

....

var result = new List<T>(boardData);
result.AddRange(classData);
...

return Json(result);
```

Notice that you won't have different properties for your angular side, though, so you should create a class to hold these lists instead of merging them.

Comment: Thanks for the Ans @Camilo. I'm using Task.Factory.StartNew to run the FetchTableData parallel . So that my list will take less time to load. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Deepak Yes, you are wrong. First of all, you are not doing it in parallel since you are using `await`. Second, you should use `Task.Run` but there's no point there since `FetchTblData` is what should be asynchronous

Comment: Also, If I Make FetchTblData return a IEnumerable<T> it will effect the result which I'm fetching in other angular functions.

Comment: @Deepak Yes, that's an architectural change. Domain logic should not be bound to the client logic

Comment: So can you suggest something to run my FetchTableData parallel for multiple lists?

Comment: @Deepak Sure, you would have to create a `Task` (use `Task.Run` if you cannot change `FetchTblData`) and call `await Task.WhenAll` instead of calling `await FetchTblData`.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know what is data type of .Data but this part looking wrong.

```
var result = new { resBoard.Data + resClass.Data + resClassSubject.Data + resClassMaterial.Data };
```

You can fix as

```
var result = new { data = resBoard.Data + resClass.Data + resClassSubject.Data + resClassMaterial.Data };
```

But i gues it must be

```
var result = new {
 resBoard = resBoard.Data,
 resClass = resClass.Data,
 resClassSubject = resClassSubject.Data,
 resClassMaterial = resClassMaterial.Data
};
```

Or you can return an array

```
var result = new DATA_TYPE[] {
 resBoard.Data,
 resClass.Data,
 resClassSubject.Data,
 resClassMaterial.Data
};
```

I hope this helped